# How to Add Button to Textfield in view

Tags: ios

```
UITextField *tf3 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, tf2.frame.origin.y+55,100, 30)];
tf3.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/256.0 green:84/256.0 blue:129/256.0 alpha:1.0];
//tf.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:25];
tf3.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
tf3.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleLine;
tf3.placeholder=@"Save";
tf3.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,270, 100, 40)];
[view1 addSubview:tf3];
```

how can I add save button to this `textField` without using storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Code,

```
       UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
       button.frame = CGRectMake(65, 0, 35, 30);
       button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
       [button setTitle:@"Save" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
       [tf3 addSubview:button];
```

hope its helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can add it something like

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[tf3 addSubview:btn]
```

Answer (score 0):

> The right way:

In UITextField you have two properties / left view and right view / see how to enable them.

i think is something like:

```
tf3.leftViewMode = .AlwaysEnabled // Here you can place a enum options, such as always visible, visible only while edit and stuff
```

> Next Step:
>   Create a UIButton:

```
var saveButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0:, width: 30, height: 30)
saveButton.setImage(named: "your_imgae", state: .Normal)
saveButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(saveButtonPressed(_:) ...)
tf3.leftView = saveButton
```

> Next Step
>   Create a function `saveButtonPressed(sender: UIButton)` and listen there for click event.

I haven't test it, but i think it should work.